Convert a .docx from a markdown document into pdf in Shiny
I have a markdown file, that generates a .docx document. I also have a shiny app with a button, that generates that .docx document to download it.
I want to create a second Downloadhandler that converts that .docx file into a pdf and let's the user download that.
Here is the working part of the server.R that handles the .docx part:
# download ----
  output$pdf <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "Test.docx",
    content = function(file) {
      rmarkdown::render("Test.Rmd",
                         output_file = file,
                         envir = new.env(parent = globalenv()))      
    })

Is there a way to do this? I have found ways to convert .dcox to .pdf in general (How to convert docx to PDF?, Writing doc output to pdf), but they need to have a local copy of word or libreoffice installed. As the shinyapp will run on a server somewhere i cannot do it that way.
I am open to alternative ways to handle the problem. I am aware that i could also create a pdf out of my markdown file, but this will inevitable look different, as i cannot use my word-template for it and other reasons. I need these Downloads to look identical though.
Is there a way to achieve this?

pandoc, which is powering quarto under the hood, can do that, but the PDF won't look exactly like the docx. In that case you could directly go to the PDF from the markdown though.

Where are you deploying it? If it's not shinyapps.io there's no reason why you couldn't install libreoffice.

it currently is shinyapps.io but thats more like a testphase. I have not yet looked into hosting shinyapps myself but on the long run that is definitly the plan. I guess i didnt think about it, but yes, you are right, i might be able to indeed use libreoffice.
I would prefer if it also worked on shinyapps, but will settle for that if not. Thanks for the comment!
